# Bash: Determine partially deleted content

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to delete a symbolic link

`rm -rf name`

but instead used

`rm -rf name/`

I think it took me a second to realize the mistake and cancelled it. This is a massive directory with hundreds of gbs of data. So it would take a long time to delete anyway.

1. Since the command was incomplete, are the partially processed files restored (like `mv`) or are they already permanently deleted?
2. If they are irrecoverably deleted, is it possible to find out what has been deleted? Is it deleted in the the same order as `ls` (alphabetical)?
3. Is there a log of files deleted from the system?

OS is Scientific Linux. File system is nfs (`df -T`).

Comment: Not a bash question. You'd have the *exact* same behavior from any tool (shell, programming language, etc) calling `rm`, or even calling the `unlink()` syscall directly.

Comment: ...not really a programming question, either. I'd suggest either http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that said -- any files that were unlinked are prone to having their blocks reallocated to new content that's written. No, cancelling the process does not restore links.

Comment: If you have programs already running which have the deleted files open, *don't exit those programs* -- the very fact that a file is in use by a piece of running software increments that file's reference count and prevents it from being permanently unlinked.

Comment: If you can do so without terminating running programs, you should seriously consider remounting the filesystem in question read-only -- this will prevent new contents from being written, which will prevent the blocks from being reused, which (if it happened) would eliminate any chance of recoverability for data in those blocks.

Comment: ...now, the further answers are operating-system-specific, not bash-specific, so applicability of the advice below all depends on details you haven't given. However:

Comment: If you're using Linux, you can create hardlinks from procfs to prevent a file that's otherwise deleted but still in-use from being removed permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The OS is Scientific Linux.

Comment: If such a file is FD 9 to PID 1234, for instance, you can `ln /prod/1234/fd/9 /my/fs/recovered-name` to create a link called `recovered-name` to that file; `/my/fs` needs to be the same filesystem where this lived previously.

Comment: Look up which filesystem type was in use for the partition on which the files lived -- you'll want to find undelete tools that are specifically built to support that filesystem.

Comment: so, if it's ext4, "undelete ext4" would be what you'd want to search for. Hopefully you aren't using anything too experimental or exotic.

Comment: (BTW, re: already-running-programs-with-deleted-files-open, you might want to send a SIGSTOP, if they'll honor it, so they don't try to write more contents and thus potentially reuse blocks freed during the deletion, making the files which had been using those blocks unrecoverable).

Comment: `lsof` is a good tool to use in identifying such programs, by the way; it shows file handles pointing at deleted content clearly, and in a manner easy to grep for.

Comment: I think I have nfs filesystem. I am using a shared cluster, so I have limited admin previlages.

Comment: Ouch. You'll need the admin who owns the file server to help you -- and if there are other users whose write access to the relevant filesystem can't afford to be cut off temporarily, it might be very hard for them to do anything helpful here.

Comment: On the other hand, it's possible that they're using a filesystem such as zfs or btrfs that supports snapshotting, or otherwise have a recovery mechanism in place for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :  Last point might be interesting to op.

Comment: I think recovery is going to be too complicated. Besides these are not super critical files. Couple of weeks of work. They can be recreated from backed up raw files. But the important part is that I figure out what has been deleted.

Comment: I'd at least suggest asking. Depending on how they're set up, it *may* be entirely trivial to retrieve the files as they existed as of the last nightly snapshot (or such). Can't hurt to enquire.

Comment: This doesn't help you now, but the `-r` option wasn't necessary to just remove a single symlink. `rm -f name/` would then have failed to remove a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I still hold the question to be off-topic here... but it can't hurt to have explicit answers to every branch of the question in one place, and if this answer gets migrated to SuperUser with the question, all the better:

---

> 1. Since the command was incomplete, are the partially processed files restored (like mv) or are they already permanently deleted?

Just like an individual `rename()` syscall during a recursive `mv` within a single filesystem, an individual `unlink()` of a single file is atomic -- it either completes or it doesn't on a file-by-file basis. There's no "half-done" state, and no larger transaction spanning multiple files that can be rolled back; **each individual directory entry** will either be deleted, or not.

Likewise, any file which has no remaining directory entries (aka "hardlinks") pointing to it or open file handles at the end of an `unlink()` will immediately be subject to deletion -- though the filesystem is at its own discretion as to whether, when, and under what circumstances to actually wipe or reuse the underlying blocks where its data was stored, or the tracking data which specified which blocks were associated with each now-deleted file.

> 2. If they are irrecoverably deleted, is it possible to find out what has been deleted? Is it deleted in the the same order as ls (alphabetical)?

Not in general. There exist specific backend filesystems that could be used that can track either changes between snapshots or even do point-in-time recovery (though these are generally commercial and thus only available if your administrator was paying for them), and monitoring tools (such as `sysdig`) that record individual syscalls.

If your system administrator is running ZFS or btrfs with cronned snapshots, for instance, they can compare the list of files that currently exist to those that existed as of the last snapshot.

> 3. Is there a log of files deleted from the system?

Not in general. If your site is running Sysdig Cloud, or a commercial fileserver with non-default behavior, then maybe -- but your sysadmin staff would be the people who could answer that question.

Comment: I contacted the admin, and turns out snapshots were enabled. Then I could just compare current directory with an older snapshot using `diff` and 4 large files were deleted which were easily restored. Thanks for the help.